# three.js Creating Text inside of Placeholder Mesh / World Coordinates?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm currently working with three.js - it's my first venture into 3D graphic programming really. I followed along a tutorial on creating a 2D configurator that allows me to change materials on a externally loaded model. I now try to create a demo where I can add / change 3D details of a given model.

I can load the model from an obj file, including the materials and I can change materials etc. just fine. I can also look / move stuff around the scene.

You can see the full code [here](https://rjhllr.github.io/three-obj-demo/). A debugger breakpoint is added inside of the rerender function.

In my model, I've added a "placeholder" mesh where I want to add text:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3D Configurator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas width="800" height="800" id="viewport"></canvas>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
        var elem = document.querySelector('#viewport')
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: viewport,
            antialias: true
        });
        renderer.setSize( elem.width, elem.height );
        var elem = document.querySelector('#viewport')
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, elem.width/elem.height, 0.1, 1000 );
        var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
        var materialLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        var modelLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        var materialsFromServer = materialLoader.parse(getMtl())
        objectFromServer = modelLoader.setMaterials(materialsFromServer).parse(getObj());
        loader.load( 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {
            objectFromServer.rotation.x = -1.3;
            objectFromServer.rotation.y = 6.2;
            objectFromServer.rotation.z = 0.8;
            scene.add(objectFromServer);    

            placeholderMesh = objectFromServer.children.find(e => e.name === 'textPlaceholder');
            console.log(placeholderMesh.getWorldPosition());

            var newText = generateText('test1234', font);
            newText.rotation.x = 6;
            newText.rotation.y = 25.3;
            newText.rotation.z = 25;
            newText.position.x = -50;
            newText.position.y = 40;
            newText.position.z = 13;
            scene.add(newText);

            camera.position.y = -2;
            camera.position.z = 150;

            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
            scene.add(ambientLight);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        });

        function getMtl() {
            return `# Color definition for Tinkercad Obj File 2015

            newmtl color_6383466
            Ka 0 0 0 
            Kd 0.3803921568627451 0.403921568627451 0.41568627450980394
            d 1
            illum 0.0

            newmtl color_15277357
            Ka 0 0 0 
            Kd 0.9137254901960784 0.11372549019607843 0.17647058823529413
            d 1
            illum 0.0

            `;
        }

        function getObj() {
            return `# Object Export From Tinkercad Server 2015

            mtllib obj.mtl

            o obj_0
            v 0         -11         0
            v 0         -11         20
            v 0         -24.9972        20
            v 0         -31         13.9976
            v 0         -31         0
            v -15.032       -12.124         20
            v -13.64        -13.982         20
            v -50       -11         20
            v -50       -11         0
            v -50       -31         0
            v -14.255       -21.013         0
            v -50       -31         13.9976
            v -13.215       -18.847         0
            v -12.998       -16.36      20
            v -50       -24.9972        20
            v -22.6997      -24.9972        20
            v -22.948       -26.296         20
            v -22.941       -26.4095        20
            v -13.215       -18.847         20
            v -22.9044      -27         20
            v -15.938       -22.483         0
            v -20.007       -22.483         0
            v -20.007       -22.483         20
            v -14.255       -21.013         20
            v -17.973       -23.002         0
            v -8        -31         25
            v -8        -31         20
            v -8        -27         20
            v -8        -27         25
            v -15.938       -22.483         20
            v -28       -27         25
            v -28       -27         20
            v -14.254       -31         18.1259
            v -28       -31         20
            v -28       -31         25
            v -17.973       -23.002         20
            v -14.254       -28.9358        16.0618
            v -16.933       -11.107         0
            v -19.013       -11.107         0
            v -22.73        -27.4047        17.5927
            v -21.69        -21.013         0
            v -22.948       -25.6468        19.3505
            v -14.1487      -31         18.4361
            v -13.2443      -24.9972        20
            v -19.013       -11.107         20
            v -21.69        -21.013         20
            v -16.933       -11.107         20
            v -15.8543      -31         16.1492
            v -13.214       -29.812         20
            v -22.948       -25.6466        19.3506
            v -15.9368      -29.9752        15.0224
            v -13.214       -27.4047        17.5927
            v -13.214       -29.812         20
            v -22.7299      -27.4048        17.5926
            v -12.998       -16.36      0
            v -15.937       -31         16.047
            v -15.937       -29.9753        15.0223
            v -22.73        -18.847         0
            v -13.6175      -31         20
            v -22.73        -18.847         20
            v -17.972       -30.3428        14.6548
            v -14.2539      -28.9356        16.0619
            v -13.214       -27.4046        17.5928
            v -13.1918      -29.4543        20
            v -22.948       -16.36      0
            v -22.948       -16.36      20
            v -21.69        -28.9358        16.0618
            v -22.305       -13.982         0
            v -22.305       -13.982         20
            v -22.3265      -31         20
            v -13.0397      -27         20
            v -20.913       -12.124         0
            v -20.913       -12.124         20
            v -21.6899      -28.9358        16.0617
            v -20.007       -29.9753        15.0223
            v -12.996       -26.296         20
            v -13.0137      -26.2032        20
            v -21.69        -31         18.1259
            v -21.5386      -31         17.939
            v -15.032       -12.124         0
            v -20.007       -31         16.047
            v -13.64        -13.982         0
            v -17.972       -31         15.312
            v -22.73        -29.812         20
            v -22.6072      -30.1738        20
            v -12.996       -25.6466        19.3506
            v -12.996       -25.6465        19.3508
            # 87 vertices

            g group_0_6383466

            usemtl color_6383466
            s 0

            f 5     1   4
            f 3     4   1
            f 3     1   2
            f 3     2   14
            f 71    76  18
            f 20    71  18
            f 10    12  9
            f 12    15  9
            f 8     9   15
            f 22    23  36
            f 22    36  25
            f 15    12  42
            f 36    44  30
            f 16    17  36
            f 3     24  44
            f 50    15  42
            f 49    43  53
            f 48    51  37
            f 1     38  39
            f 1     39  9
            f 41    46  23
            f 41    23  22
            f 47    2   45
            f 6     2   47
            f 6     7   2
            f 8     45  2
            f 21    11  5
            f 1     5   13
            f 1     13  55
            f 55    82  1
            f 40    42  12
            f 56    57  51
            f 56    51  48
            f 59    43  49
            f 52    53  43
            f 58    60  46
            f 58    46  41
            f 61    4   57
            f 37    62  33
            f 43    33  62
            f 19    3   14
            f 24    3   19
            f 30    44  24
            f 7     14  2
            f 25    5   10
            f 22    25  10
            f 5     25  21
            f 11    13  5
            f 63    64  52
            f 53    52  64
            f 43    62  52
            f 60    58  65
            f 60    65  66
            f 51    4   37
            f 51    57  4
            f 37    4   62
            f 65    58  9
            f 10    9   58
            f 68    65  9
            f 68    69  66
            f 68    66  65
            f 16    46  15
            f 69    8   66
            f 15    66  8
            f 70    78  43
            f 54    12  67
            f 72    73  69
            f 72    69  68
            f 79    67  74
            f 74    12  75
            f 67    12  74
            f 78    79  43
            f 70    43  59
            f 10    41  22
            f 36    23  16
            f 77    44  17
            f 39    45  73
            f 39    73  72
            f 48    33  79
            f 80    6   47
            f 80    47  38
            f 36    17  44
            f 17    18  77
            f 76    77  18
            f 75    81  74
            f 79    74  81
            f 10    58  41
            f 60    15  46
            f 23    46  16
            f 81    56  79
            f 82    7   6
            f 82    6   80
            f 61    83  75
            f 81    75  83
            f 66    15  60
            f 54    40  12
            f 16    15  50
            f 55    14  7
            f 55    7   82
            f 83    56  81
            f 48    79  56
            f 33    43  79
            f 61    75  12
            f 4     61  12
            f 10    5   12
            f 4     12  5
            f 4     3   63
            f 87    86  3
            f 44    87  3
            f 13    19  14
            f 13    14  55
            f 71    63  76
            f 2     1   9
            f 45    8   73
            f 69    73  8
            f 9     39  72
            f 9     72  68
            f 63    52  4
            f 11    24  19
            f 11    19  13
            f 86    76  63
            f 64    63  71
            f 80    38  1
            f 2     9   8
            f 62    4   52
            f 21    30  24
            f 21    24  11
            f 82    80  1
            f 86    63  3
            f 87    77  86
            f 76    86  77
            f 77    87  44
            f 16    50  17
            f 30    21  25
            f 30    25  36
            f 18    42  40
            f 84    20  40
            f 18    40  20
            f 38    47  45
            f 38    45  39
            f 17    50  42
            f 17    42  18
            f 37    33  48
            f 54    78  85
            f 70    85  78
            f 67    78  54
            f 84    40  54
            f 84    54  85
            f 78    67  79
            f 83    61  57
            f 83    57  56
            # 151 faces

            g textPlaceholder

            usemtl color_15277357
            s 0

            f 26    27  28
            f 26    28  29
            f 31    32  34
            f 31    34  35
            f 29    31  35
            f 29    35  26
            f 27    64  28
            f 35    34  70
            f 59    26  70
            f 27    26  59
            f 35    70  26
            f 27    59  49
            f 27    49  53
            f 29    28  71
            f 29    71  20
            f 32    31  20
            f 29    20  31
            f 53    64  27
            f 71    28  64
            f 20    84  32
            f 34    32  84
            f 84    85  34
            f 70    34  85
            # 23 faces

            #end of obj_0`;
        }


        function generateGeometry(textParam, font) {
            return new THREE.TextGeometry( textParam, {
                font: font,
                size: 6,
                height: .1  ,
                curveSegments: 12,
                bevelEnabled: true,
                bevelThickness: 1,
                bevelSize: .1   ,
                bevelOffset: 0,
                bevelSegments: 5
            } );
        }

        function generateText(textParam, font) {
            var textGeometry = generateGeometry(textParam, font);
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00000 } ));
            mesh.name = 'customText';
            mesh.castShadow = true;
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;
            return mesh;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the red part is the placeholder mesh where I want my text to be.

With my limited experience I think I need to get world coordinates for the mesh in question. I can get the mesh from the loaded group just fine, however accessing it's coordinates using getWorldPosition() always returns 0|0|0, unless I change the local position directly (`objectFromServer.location.x = 123; objectFromServer.updateMatrixWorld`/ `translateX`), however the rotation does not influence the return of "getWorldPosition()" at all (but obviously does influence the object's real "position" in what I see in the preview)

What is the recommended way to get proper coordinates, taking into account rotation and such?
Then, how would I go about moving my text (TextGeometry) to this exact location, again taking into account rotation etc.

Can I use the element's bounding box as text boundaries in some way?

You can see the full code [here](https://rjhllr.github.io/three-obj-demo/). A debugger breakpoint is added inside of the rerender function.

Comment: Please show more of your code. How is the red mesh created? Is it nested in another object? Did you move its position, or is the geometry shifted? We need to see your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Don't use obj, use GLTF. obj has no hierarchy of information so that placeholder part (which I'm assuming is part of the obj file) has no more info than its vertices. If you use GLTF instead then the hierarchy you see in your modeling tool will also get imported into three.js and that part won't return 0,0,0 for its world position.

Comment: Thank you Marquizzo, I moved and rotated objects just to make them somewhat visible in the preview. I added a demo link, including a debugger breakpoint for the relevant rerender function. The red mesh is nested and comes from an imported OBJ file's group.

Comment: @RobinHeller, posting a link to code offsite is offtopic for stackoverflow. If the question needs code you need to make it the minimal code needed and put it in the question itself.

Comment: @gman thanks for the GLTF pointer, I'll look into it. Also: I didn't want to post offsite code, but I depend on importing that obj file. Does SO provide somewhere to host that? I looked into CodePen and SOs integrated HTML/CSS/JS snippet tool. But posting code without making the assets available permanently doesn't really help, does it?

Comment: @RobinHeller, no there is no way to post an obj file directly. This is part of making your example minimal. You should be able to make a .obj file with say 2 cubes to repo the issue and include it in your example. You could load it with [`ObjLoader.parse`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/OBJLoader.parse) or you could use github pages to host the file but still put your **MINIMAL** example in the question itself.

Comment: I added the embedded example as well now, tried to make it as small as possible. I didn't know about ObjLoader/MtlLoader.parse. Thank you!